# Separate observations not joining in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

So this [data frame](https://www.dropbox.com/s/go1psdfpzq1sc4u/Total_Frame?dl=0) has a lot of separate observations that I need to be added together.

Use dget():

I've tried a lot of different solutions like:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(product, price) %>% 
  summarise(
    quantity = sum(quantity),
    total = sum(total)
  )
```

And:

```
df %>%
  gather(key = variable, value = value, c(Quantity,Price,Total)) %>%
  group_by(Product, variable) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(variable, sum)
```

And:

```
df %>%
          group_by(Product) %>%
          summarise(Quantity = sum(Quantity),
          AveragePrice = sum(Total)/sum(Quantity),
          Total = sum(Total))
```

but i just get:

```
> df
  quantity total
1       61  1685
```

Expected output is something like this but obviously with all the products on the `product` column:

```
#> # Groups:   product [2]
#>   product        price quantity total
#>   <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 small cucumber    10        1    10
#> 2 tomatoes 1kg      16        2    32
```

I have asked this before but I wasn't nearly specific enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `plyr::summarise` instead of `dplyr::summarise`. You can call it explicitly with

```
df %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    Quantity = sum(Quantity),
    AveragePrice = sum(Total)/sum(Quantity),
    Total = sum(Total))
#> # A tibble: 27 x 4
#>    Product                      Quantity AveragePrice Total
#>    <chr>                           <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 asparagus 200g                      4           45   180
#>  2 back bacon 200g                     1           30    30
#>  3 beef fillet strips 500g             1           90    90
#>  4 beetroot 1kg                        1           15    15
#>  5 broccoli head                       1           25    25
#>  6 butter 500g                         1           57    57
#>  7 butternut cubes                     4           14    56
#>  8 calistos jalape=c3=b1o salsa        1           40    40
#>  9 carrot 1 kg                         4           14    56
#> 10 cauliflower whole head              2           25    50
#> # … with 17 more rows
```

Comment: You legend I cant believe it was that simple . Thank you so much I've learnt the importance of specifying the package I want to use.